# How can I access aria-expanded value of a button

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

How can I access button properties from click listener? I want to access aria-expanded to set some values; here is what I got.

**x.html**

```
<button class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="customSearch($event.target)" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseForm" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseForm">Search</button>
```

**x.ts**

```
  customSearch(e){
    console.log("some event--->",e);
  }
```

**result**

[image]

Comment: Did you try ``this.getAttribute("aria-expanded")``?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are already passing the dom object as parameter you could directly get its attribute using getAttribute method

```js
 customSearch(buttonDOM) {
    console.log("some event--->", buttonDOM.getAttribute('aria-expanded'));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to create a directive that modifies your button this is an example

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
    selector: '[aextended]'
})
export class AextendedDirective {
    constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer) {

    }
    @HostListener('click') onClick() {
     this.el.nativeElement.setAttribute('aria-expanded','true');
    }
}
```

and then in your template

```
<button aextended class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="customSearch($event.target)" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseForm" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseForm">Search</button>
```

this is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m2v6tn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) of a working case

if you really want to set it from controller you can do this

```
  customSearch(el){
    el.setAttribute('aria-expanded','true')
  }
```